# How to toggle visibility of a subset of patches in an axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I'd like to toggle the visibility of a subset of PolygonPatches in an `Axes` instance, after adding them as a PatchCollection, but I'm not sure if there's an efficient way to do that.

Is there a way of getting a subset of the patches from the `Axes` instance, then toggling their visibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is sure possible. You can directly use `PatchCollection.set_visible()` to show and hide the PatchCollection.

Then, use a `Button` to toggle visibility.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

patches = []
for i in range(3):
    polygon = Polygon(np.random.rand(3, 2), True)
    patches.append(polygon)

colors = 100*np.random.rand(len(patches))
p = PatchCollection(patches, alpha=0.4)
p.set_array(np.array(colors))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(p)

bax = fig.add_axes([0.45,0.91,0.1,0.05])
button = Button(bax, "toggle")

def update(event):
    p.set_visible(not p.get_visible())
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

button.on_clicked(update)

plt.show()
```